# React firestore image array of URL is not getting stored

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.addData = this.addData.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      username: "",
      imgFile: [],
      imgUrl: [],
    };
  }
  upload = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.storeImageAndgetUrl(this.addData);
  };
  storeImageAndgetUrl = (addData) => {
    const imgUrl = [];
    const storage = fire.storage();
    const ref = storage.ref();
    this.state.imgFile.forEach((file) => {
      ref
        .child(file.name)
        .put(file)
        .then(
          (snapShot) => {
            console.log(snapShot);
            const storage = fire.storage();

            this.state.imgFile.forEach((file) => {
              const ref = storage.ref(file.name);
              ref.getDownloadURL().then((fireBaseUrl) => {
                console.log(fireBaseUrl);
                imgUrl.push(fireBaseUrl);
              });
            });
            this.setState({ imgUrl });
          },
          (err) => {
            console.log(err);
          }
        );
    });
    addData();
  };
  addData = () => {
    // const images = this.state.imgUrl;
    console.log(this.state.imgUrl);
    fire.firestore().collection("new").add({
      name: this.state.username,
      img: this.state.imgUrl,
    });
  };
  handleChangeUsername = (e) => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };
  setImage = (e) => {
    if (Array.from(e.target.files[0]).length < 4) {
      const img = Array.from(e.target.files);
      this.setState({ imgFile: img });
    } else {
      alert("You can select maximum 5 Images");
    }
  };
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.username);
    console.log(this.state.imgFile);
    console.log(this.state.imgUrl);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <form onSubmit={this.upload}>
          <label>Username:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.username}
            name="username"
            onChange={this.handleChangeUsername}
          />
          <input
            type="file"
            accept="image/*"
            onChange={this.setImage}
            multiple
          />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**In the above code, I'm storing multiple array of images and fetching the URL of those images using call back and storing the URL in firestore. Image array of URL is not getting stored. I have made a callback function where I'm storing images and another function where the Fetched URL Array to store in firestore**

Comment: Have you ever tried without reactJS and how did it go?

Comment: No Sir, I didn't try without react

Comment: Don't repost the same question multiple times please. If you have additional information, edit your original question to include that.